# Post method not working in this temp.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Post method not working:

```
var user = {
   "user4" : {
      "name" : "mohit",
      "password" : "password4",
      "profession" : "teacher",
      "id": 4
   }
}

app.post('/addUser', function (req, res) {
   // First read existing users.
   fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
       data = JSON.parse( data );
       data["user4"] = user["user4"];
       console.log( data );
       res.end( JSON.stringify(data));
   });
})
```

And I'm trying to access this by passing:
`http://127.0.0.1:7000/addUser`

Please help me through this.

The error is like this:

> Cannot GET /addUser

Comment: it seems that the port number is missing

Comment: "Cannot GET /addUser" you set the route to accept POST, not GET, so use that or change `.post` to `.get`

Comment: I thought that it is not relevant and understood so I posted parts of code. @elarmando

Comment: But what will I do if I'm using another html form to post these data seperately. @casraf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to use the GET HTTP verb and not POST you could either:

- Test this using a tool such as Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) or use cURL to POST.
- Change POST to GET and open it from within your browser.
- Create a HTML Form element w/ the required fields and submit the form to the POST url.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can do GET here. But what if I'm doing this from other HTML form?

Comment: Then you'll need to create a form to POST first.

Comment: I'd recommend you create a form on another page to POST to this endpoint, and you should see it working.

Comment: Okay, I'll come back to you after trying that.

Answer (score 0):

A browser's URL bar will always make a GET request, not a POST. So you need to define your route as such :

```
app.get('/addUser', ....
```

instead of

```
app.post('/addUser', ....
```